# Getting data to Android app from google app engine datastore

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I have created a datastore on the google app engine but would like to be able to view this data on an android emulator for example if the user requests so. I am a beginner in developing android apps so it is quite hard to follow some examples online. Could someone tell me a simple way to solve this problem or post a link which will direct me to an easy tutorial/source code to follow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way would be to use [LeanEngine](http://www.lean-engine.com/):

1. There is the GAE server part that you can just simply upload to your GAE account. Most functionality is in a jar, so you can easily add it to your existing project if you have one.
2. There is also an example Android app to get you started ASAP.

It's open source. Also, it let's users authenticate via Facebook or OpenID.

Comment: Thanks @PeterKnego. This looks a very good place to start for me.